# Elixir: How to handle an "environment"

Tags: elixir

I've got a fairly big "pipeline" of functions processing a stream of inputs.
Before the pipeline starts an "environment" map is created that will provide additional
information for the functions in the pipeline.  What I'm doing now, which seems
to be what Elixir demands is to explicitly pass the environment into each function.

I'm a bit uneasy about the readability of the requirement that each function in the
pipeline (and many of the functions they call) requires the environment as an argument.
On the other hand I certainly understand that this may just be a part of "doing it
functionally".

My question is:  Am I missing something, perhaps an idiom, to handle this issue,
or should I just get used to passing what seem like "extra" arguments as part of
the functional programming world?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using Agents for this. The following is completely made up, but shows you the different operations, and resembles how you might want to approach it:

```rb
def process(data) do
  {:ok, agent} = Agent.start_link(fn -> %{data: data, count: 0} end)
  process(data, agent)
end

def process(agent) when is_pid(agent) and bar > 0 do
  transformed = do_stuff_with(data)
  Agent.get_and_update(agent, fn %{count: count} = state ->
    updated = %{state | :data => transformed, :count => count + 1}
    {updated, updated}
  end
  process(agent)
end

def process(agent) when is_pid(agent) and bar == 0 do
  Agent.cast(agent, fn %{count: count} = state ->
    %{state | :count => count + 1}
  end
  process(agent)
end

def process(agent) when is_pid(agent) do
  Agent.get(agent, fn state -> state.data end)
end
```

Instead of passing state, you pass the PID of the agent around, and get/update the Agent's state as needed.

Comment: Yes, thanks. That seems right and very Elixir-natural.

Comment: How is this different than passing the map itself around?

Comment: I updated my example because I forgot to remove passing the original data around. The general idea though is that Agent's store temporary state, such as you might have during some complex processing. You can explicitly pass all that state around, or you can use an Agent to manage it. Fundamentally you accomplish the same goal, it's highly dependent on the context though which path you would choose. Perhaps not all stages of processing require the current state, and you don't want to pass stuff around that isn't used. This solution is simply an alternative to the explicit passing of state.

Comment: I don't think using processes just to avoid passing arguments is a proper way to go. Processes should be used when you want fault-tolerance and/or scalability. Admittedly, original question is somewhat vague, but I don't see mention of such concepts there. Using processes may actually bring additional problems, such as performance decrease (due to message passing back and forth) and more complicated logs (since an error may now happen in two different process). So, while processes are definitely useful, I wouldn't say they're "the" solution for passing state through various functions.